# Validation in Laravel to exclude æøå

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to make a validation in Laravel, that excludes the user from creating a subdomain with the letters ÆØÅ(I live in Denmark)
Have tried a lot of different thing, but I can only seem to get it to work, if æ, ø or å are the first letters, not if it's after that. Code looks like this

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:organizations,name,'.$this->id,
        'subdomain' => 'required|max:255|regex:/[a-z\-]+/i|unique:organizations,subdomain,'.$this->id,
        'address' => 'required|regex:/^[a-z0-9- .]+/i|min:2',
        'zip_code' => 'required|numeric',
        'city' => 'required|regex:/^[a-z0-9- .]+/i|min:2',
        'country' => 'required|max:2',
        'cvr' => 'required|numeric|min:8',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Missing start `^` and end `$` anchors?

Comment: Yes, try `/^[a-z-]+$/i`. The original question has the same solution: adding anchors.